# Circular dependency when generating Angular library

Tags: angular, circular-dependency, angular-library

**Edit**

It appears that the circular dependency pops up only when using production build - `ng build lib --prod`

---

I am generating an Angular library to be used in a different Angular project. However, when compiling the code, I get a circular dependency warning in one of my barrels. This is my code:

**modal.controller.ts**

```
import { BackdropController } from './backdrop-controller';

export class ModalController {
  ...
}
```

*Disclaimer: BackdropController does not import either ModalController or Barrel (index.controller.ts)*

**index.controllers.ts**

```
export * from './backdrop-controller';
export * from './modal-controller';
```

Now the code above seems correct to me. `ModalController` is importing only `BackdropController` directly and not importing anything from the barrel. From standpoint of Angular application,  I would say this is absolutely correct and doesn't create circular dependency.

However! When building the project, I do get a circular dependency. The output (simplified) if the build file is similar to this:

**index.controller.js**

```
export * from './backdrop.controller';
export * from './modal.controller';
```

**modal.controller.js**

```
import { BackdropController } from '../backdrop/backdrop.controller';
import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
import * as i1 from '../_index';

export class ModalController {
  ...
}
new i1.ModalController(...)
```

The problem in the compiled code seems to be the module building. On line 3, the barrel is imported as `import * as i1 from '../_index'` and ModalController is then added to module `i1` in the end - `import * as i1 from '../_index'`

Is there a way to fix such circular dependency which appears only when building the code?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I've faced with the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

One solution is (tested in angular 12) to set `compilationMode` to `full`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "full"
  }
}
```

It isn't a perfect solution but it works.
You can see what it does [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG3003)

Another solution (uses dynamic components) is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047200/ng3003-angular-12-circular-dependency-in-library-ivy-partial-compilationmode/70078485#70078485).

Also I found these two articles very useful about this. ([Angular Linker](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/01/27/angular-linker/) and [Ivy library compilation](https://blog.lacolaco.net/2021/02/angular-ivy-library-compilation-design-in-depth-en/)) 

Let me know if it did fix your problem.